# How to make Lean FingerSwipe event trigger at the beginning of swipe?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, touch

I am developing a mobile game in Unity for which I need the controls to be very responsive. I use the Lean Touch asset for touch detection.
I am controlling my player with Lean FingerSwipe script, on four directions (UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT), which triggers at the end of the swipe.

My problem is that I want the event to trigger at the beginning of the swipe, not at the end, but I can't find a way to do that. Do you know if there is an option or argument to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the swipe feel responsive by triggering it exactly at the moment when the finger delta crosses the swipe threshold. As opposed to waiting for the finger to be lifted.

Copy and modify **LeanFingerSwipe.cs** from LeanTouch examples.

Firstly, instead of `OnFingerSwipe` subscribe to `OnFingerSet`.

```
LeanTouch.OnFingerSet += HandleFingerSwipe;
```

Secondly, inside the `HandleFingerSwipe` function, add a guard.

```
if (finger.SwipeScreenDelta.magnitude * LeanTouch.ScalingFactor > LeanTouch.Instance.SwipeThreshold)
{
    HandleFingerSwipe(finger, finger.StartScreenPosition, finger.ScreenPosition);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest and most accurate answer I've ever had about a technical question that I was struggling with. Thank you very much sir, it could not work better now.

Answer (score 0):

LeanTouch.OnFingerSet is no longer available. It has been updated:

**Renamed LeanTouch.OnFingerSet to LeanTouch.OnFingerUpdate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).